# Pin UIView to one of 4 spots after user drags it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want my UIView to be movable by the user, but then shift to one of the 4 corners (whichever is closest to user's final touch) - kind of like the sec camera window in FaceTime. Is there any existing method to help me? Or should I just manually calculate the distance between the user's last position and the 4 corners, and make it animate moving to the closest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method animates a view to the nearest corner of it's superview...

```
- (void)pinToCorner:(UIView *)view {
    CGPoint parentCenter = view.superview.center;
    CGPoint viewCenter = view.center;

    CGSize parentSize = view.superview.bounds.size;
    CGSize viewSize = view.bounds.size;

    CGPoint targetOrigin;

    if (viewCenter.x < parentCenter.x && viewCenter.y < parentCenter.y) {
        // top left
        targetOrigin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    } else if (viewCenter.x < parentCenter.x && viewCenter.y >= parentCenter.y) {
        // bottom left
        targetOrigin = CGPointMake(0, parentSize.height-viewSize.height);
    } else if (viewCenter.x >= parentCenter.x && viewCenter.y < parentCenter.y) {
        // top right
        targetOrigin = CGPointMake(parentSize.width-viewSize.width, 0);
    } else if (viewCenter.x >= parentCenter.x && viewCenter.y >= parentCenter.y) {
        // bottom right
        targetOrigin = CGPointMake(parentSize.width-viewSize.width, parentSize.height-viewSize.height);
    }
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = targetOrigin.x;
    frame.origin.y = targetOrigin.y;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        view.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Call this on with dragged view as parameter after the drag is complete.

FYI, a complete class that tests it...

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property(assign,nonatomic) CGPoint dragOrigin;
@end

@implementation ViewController

// lazy button creator
- (UIButton *)button {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:32];
    if (!button) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        button.tag = 32;
        [button setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40);
        button.center = self.view.center;
        [self.view addSubview:button];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panned:)];
        [button addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    }
    return button;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self button];
}

- (void)tapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
}

- (void)panned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.dragOrigin = gr.view.center;
    } else if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gr translationInView:gr.view];
        gr.view.center = CGPointMake(self.dragOrigin.x + translation.x, self.dragOrigin.y + translation.y);
    } else if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self pinToCorner:[self button]];
    }
}

// pinToCorner implementation from above goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use UIDynamicAnimator with UIGravityBehavior's; [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/uidynamics-in-swift/) is good tutorial, how it can be set up, but, in short, you can add UIGravityBehavior to sides, depending on the center of your view;

for example, if user ends moving at y < height / 2, you add behavior to top side, or if x < width / 2 to left, and vice versa

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it - the purpose of the class seems to be to make these motions seem realistic. I just want a clean translation. May be overkill. Super cool though!

Comment: When someone flicks the button hard enough, I want it to travel all the way in the direction that they flicked it (even if they let go of it before the boundary line). Do you think UIGravityBehavior would handle this correctly?

Comment: I think yes. try :)

Comment: Yes it does :) [This](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/229/) WWDC talk does *exactly* what I need. Thanks for the suggestion!